# lookup table AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, lookup-tables

I have a question about the number of lookup tables generated when dealing with AI. I'm reading the book AI, A modern approach and there, I read an example that the lookup table will contain

```
∑|P|^t
```

where P is possible percepts and t is the lifetime of the agent. In the book, the visual input for from a single camera, at a rate of 27 megabytes per second (30 frames per second, 640X480 pixels with 24 bits of color information) will lead to 
10^(250,000,000,000) entries in the lookup table.

To understand this, I read online and for the same hour, the visual input from
a single camera comes in at the rate of 50 megabytes per second (25 frames per second, 1000X1000 pixels with 8 bits of color and 8 bits of intensity information). So the lookup table for an
hour would be 2^(60*60*50M) entries.

Can someone explain me what's the difference between the two answers? How come they are so different?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, according to the formula the lookup tables for each rate/type and encoding would be different. Is there something I'm missing to answer?